# BoolFilter and BoolQuery in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am applying to two search requests a filter and a query semantically identical like so:

```
static FilterBuilder filter(String field1Value, String field2Value){
    return FilterBuilders.boolFilter().must(FilterBuilders.termFilter("field1",field1Value)).should(FilterBuilders.termFilter("field2",field2Value));
}
static QueryBuilder query(String field1Value, String field2Value){
    return QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("field1",field1Value)).should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("field2",field2Value));
}
client.prepareSearch(indexName).setPostFilter(filter("hello", "world")).setTypes("mytype");
client.prepareSearch(indexName).setQuery(query("hello","world")).setTypes("mytype");
```

However, while the search with the query returns results, the search with the filter doesn't return any result. Aren't the two suppose to behave identically and if not, why?

Comment: Don't use PostFilter. It removes documents _after_ the query stage. This is meant to remove documents after aggregating against some superset. You want to use the `filteredQuery` that contains your filter.

Comment: Thanks although I oversimplified.  I am doing a filtered aggregation, is that a bad idea?

Comment: Filtered aggregation is a good use. You really just want to be sure that you _really_ want to do a post filter. The other types of filters are harder to misuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not exactly the same. 
In a bool query with a must clause a document would be a match if none of the clauses in should are matched provided there is no explicit [minimum_should_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html) in the query.

In filter bool query at-least one should clause needs to be satisfied for a document to be considered a match. In filters there is no option of minimum_should_match  and can be treated as always set to one.

i.e for filters it can be viewed as follows

```
 [must_clause] && [should_clause1 || should_clause_2]
```

For the example in the OP :

1) the documents would pass the filter if and only if they match  field1 criteria in *must clause* and field2 criteria in *should clause* .

2) Whereas for bool query  it would suffice for a  document to be considered a match if must-clause is satisfied i.e field1 match

Comment: In both queries there's a must though?